# Avoid fontspec warning with babel

Tags: beamer, fontspec, babel, warnings

I have this example

```
\documentclass[hyperref=unicode]{beamer}

\usepackage[english,nil,bidi=basic-r]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar-DZ, main]{arabic}
\babelfont{rm}{Amiri}
\babelfont{sf}{Amiri}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}
\today
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{}
\selectlanguage{english}
\today
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Compiled with `lualatex` I obtain this warning

> Package fontspec Warning: Language 'English' not available for font
>   'Amiri'

What I have done wrong? or what I have missed?

Comment: Why this warning keep showing?

Comment: Sorry @Salim, I noticed the warning now. You are right. But I don't know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This bugged me for a long time too. This is what is going on:

These are the scripts and languages supported by *Amiri*:

```
DFLT        Default
arab        Arabic
arab.ARA    Arabic/Arabic
arab.KSH    Arabic/Kashmiri
arab.SND    Arabic/Sindhi
arab.URD    Arabic/Urdu
latn        Latin
latn.TRK    Latin/Turkish
```

When you load Arabic with `\babelprovide[import=ar-DZ, main]{arabic}` then `babel` reads in `babel-ar-DZ.ini`.

In this file you will find (among other things):

```
tag.opentype = ARA
script.tag.opentype = arab
```

So when Algerian Arabic is the language in use, `babel` will load *Amiri* with `arab.ARA` script and language. This exists in the font, so all is good.

But `babel-en.ini` contains this:

```
tag.opentype = ENG
script.tag.opentype = latn
```

So when English is in use, `babel` will try and load *Amiri* with `latn.ENG` script and language. Except this combination does not exist in the font, so a warning is issued by `babel`:

```
Language 'English' not available for font 'Amiri' with script 'Latin'.
```

Now all we need to do is tell `babel` to use `Language=Default` with `Script=Latin` for English while continuing to use `Language=Arabic` with `Script=Arabic` for Algerian Arabic.

To do this, remove `english` from the main `babel` options and instead load it like this:

```
\babelprovide[import,language=Default]{english}
```

**Note:** `babel` uses `language` with a lowercase `l` as opposed to `fontspec` which uses `Language`!

`babel` will now load *Amiri* with supported options for English text and no warning is issued.

## MWE

```
\documentclass[hyperref=unicode]{beamer}

\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic-r]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar-DZ, main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import, language=Default]{english}
\babelfont{rm}{Amiri}
\babelfont{sf}{Amiri}    

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}
\today
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{}
\selectlanguage{english}
\today
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am sorry, but is [my question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/618977/2288) relevant to your answer? If yes, I would be grateful to help me with it.

Answer (score 6):

You can set the language to default:

```
\documentclass[hyperref=unicode]{beamer}

\usepackage[english,nil,bidi=basic-r]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar-DZ, main]{arabic}
\babelfont{rm}[Language=Default]{Amiri}
\babelfont{sf}[Language=Default]{Amiri}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}
\today
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{}
\selectlanguage{english}
\today
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Won't that change the language for both English and Arabic to Default? `ar-DZ` asks for `Script=Arabic` and `Language=Arabic`. I thought it was better to drop `english` out of the `babel` options and instead add in `\babelprovide[import,language=Default]{english}`. This only changes the Language to Default for English text and leaves it as Arabic for Arabic text. (I'm not familiar enough with Arabic to know if this actually makes a difference in this case, but surely it would sometimes?)

Comment: Ulrike, David is right. This applies `Language=Default` to all languages, potentially breaking font features specific to some languages.

Comment: @DavidPurton Any updates? I think your solution is close to a perfect one: Instead of a forced rename from "English" to "Default", can we provide a fallback option in babel like this: `\babelprovide[import, language={English,Default}]{english}`? This will first probe the font for language "English" then gracefully fallback to "Default" if "English" doesn't exist in the font. `\babelprovide[import, fallbacktodefault]{english}` also LGTM.

Answer (score 4):

First, you can ignore this warning.  It’s harmless.  (However, I agree that it’s good practice to suppress meaningless warnings so that you don’t miss meaningful ones.)

David Purton’s answer is very elegant, but there is one situation where you might need something more complex: if you’re loading different fonts for the same language that require different options.  For example, a `\babelfont[chinese-traditional]{rm}` might support `Language=Chinese Traditional` and a `\babelfont[chinese-traditional]{sf}` might support `CJKShape = Traditional` instead.  More immediately, some Arabic fonts (including Noto Sans Arabic) do not support `Language=Arabic`.

In this case, you need to pass different `fontspec` options to the `\babelfont` command:

```
\babelfont{rm}[Scale=1.0]{Amiri}
\babelfont[english]{rm}[Language=Default]{Amiri}
```

However, a great multilingual companion font for Khaled Hosny’s Amiri is another of his font families, Libertinus.  He based Libertinus Serif on Linux Libertine and Libertinus Sans on Linux Biolinum.  I’ll let him speak as to the inspiration for the Latin letters in Amiri, but they’re a close match.  There is also a math font that you can select with `unicode-math`.

If you want to enable all the font features of these fonts, you might try the following:

```
\documentclass[hyperref=unicode]{beamer}

\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic-r]{babel}

\babelprovide[import=ar-DZ, main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en, language=Default]{english}

\babelfont{rm}[Scale=1.0,
               Ligatures={Common, TeX},
               UprightFeatures={Ligatures=Discretionary},
               Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}
              ]{Libertinus Serif}
\babelfont{sf}[Scale=MatchLowercase,
               Ligatures=TeX,
               UprightFeatures={Ligatures={Common, Discretionary}},
               BoldFeatures={Ligatures=Common}
             ]{Libertinus Sans}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}[Scale=MatchLowercase,
                       Ligatures={Common, TeX},
                       Contextuals={WordInitial,WordFinal,Inner}
                      ]{Amiri}
```

You can use the superscripts OpenType feature with the `realscripts` package.

Note that, due to a bug, Babel 3.27 and below ignores `\defaultfontfeatures` in `\babelfont`.  I’ve worked around the bug here, but a fix is making its way into the release tree.

At this point, because `beamer` uses sans-serif fonts by default, you need to define `\babelfont[arabic]{sf}`.  You can either copy the lines for `babelfont[arabic]{rm}` or load a sans-serif Arabic font, e.g.:

```
\babelfont[arabic]{sf}[Scale=MatchLowercase,
                       Ligatures=Discretionary,
                       Language=Default
                      ]{Noto Sans Arabic}
```

Answer (score 3):

Nothing wrong, on the contrary. These warnings are shown by `fontspec`, not by `babel`. They could be irrelevant for English, but not for many other languages, including Arabic. To remove them altogether (they are only really useful when the document format is being set up), you may pass the `silent` option to `fontspec`:

```
\usepackage[english,nil,bidi=basic-r]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar-DZ, main]{arabic}
\PassOptionsToPackage{silent}{fontspec}
\babelfont{rm}{Amiri}
\babelfont{sf}{Amiri}
```

Or also:

```
\usepackage[english,nil,bidi=basic-r]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar-DZ, main]{arabic}
\usepackage[silent]{fontspec}
\babelfont{rm}{Amiri}
\babelfont{sf}{Amiri}
```

**Edit.** A 3rd option is to pass `silent` as a class option.

Comment: Personally, I would only do this as a last resort. Sometimes, `fontspec` warns about something important.