# image goes right when using babel

Tags: align, hebrew

I write in Hebrew, so I use `\usepackage[hebrew]{babel}`
When I try to add hraphic with `\includegraphics{lec2-1.jpg}`, the graphic goes right and out of page:
[image]

the full code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[hebrew]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}

\includegraphics{lec2-1.jpg}
\end{center}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Would you be open to switching to `lualatex`? The old `pdflatex` Hebrew toolchain has many problems but `babel` and `lualatex` is now working really well for RTL text and it is well maintained.

Comment: When I try to use `lualatex` I got: `! Right-to-Left Support Error: use TeX--XeT or e-TeX engine.`, what I need to do? I'm using TexMaker. Thank you!

Comment: The set up is completely different for `lualatex`. Your example above won't work.

Comment: This is for a document with English as the main language, but the principle is the same for Hebrew as the main language: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/494310/87678

Comment: Thank you, It's look very uncomfortable when my main language that I write is Hebrew..

Comment: I found what to do - using `\L{\incfludinggraphic{..}}` Thank you!