# Problem using Thai script with Babel and FreeSerif typeface

Tags: luatex, fontspec, babel, unicode

The following code with compiles with a warning on Windows 10 using LuaLatex although produces a readable document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\babelprovide[main, import]{thai}
\babelfont{rm}{FreeSerif}
\begin{document}
    สวัสดี
\end{document}
```

Warning:

```
font2.tex|| Package fontspec Warning: Language 'Thai' not available for font 'FreeSerif' with script 'Thai'.
```

The following triggers an extra warning and produces a document with the Thai text missing altogether.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,thai]{babel}
\babelprovide[import]{thai}
\babelfont{rm}{FreeSerif}
\begin{document}
Hello.

\begin{otherlanguage}{thai}
    สวัสดี
\end{otherlanguage}
\end{document}
```

Warnings:

```
font_problem.tex|| Package fontspec Warning: Language 'Thai' not available for font 'FreeSerif' with script 'Thai'.
font_problem.tex|| LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LTH/FreeSerif(0)/m/n' undefined using `LTH/norasi/m/n' instead on input line 3.
```

What is causing this and how can I solve it? [FreeSerif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_FreeFont) does include Thai glyphs and the first code is taken straight from the [Latex WikiBooks's example](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Internationalization#Thai).

Comment: A font *can* have Thai glyphs, but not necessarily have the correct Thai “Script” and/or Thai “Language” setup. So this could be a font bug (or something else).

Comment: @RuixiZhang I doubt that's the case, for FreeSerif is widely used in examples, including in Babel's own documentation. When I tried this [demo from Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Multilingual_typesetting_on_Overleaf_using_babel_and_fontspec), I got a warning not just for Thai, but also for Russian and French. Even switching to Google's Noto font doesn't help.

Answer (score 3):

You must change the preamble slightly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelprovide[import, main]{thai} % Remove main if the main language is english
\babelfont{rm}{FreeSerif}
\begin{document}
Hello.

\begin{otherlanguage}{thai}
    สวัสดี
\end{otherlanguage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As to the warnings, they are usually harmless and are not errors. They are explained in the manual and also in [Avoid fontspec warning with babel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/478487/avoid-fontspec-warning-with-babel/478541#478541).

Comment: Thank you, but wouldn't that make Thai the main language? English is the main language in my document.

Comment: @bongbang In your original post `thai` was the last option when loading `babel`, so I assumed it was the main language. If it's not, just remove `main`.

Comment: I now see that I actually misread the manual. Thank you. Putting the main language last is so counter-intuitive to me that my brain automatically "fixed" it.

Comment: This example compiles, but removing `main` from the options and instead adding `[thai]` to `\babelfont` gives an “undefined control sequence” error. It works for languages like Japanese and Hindi, but not languages like Khmer or Thai… Babel gives me a headache. Any idea on what is happening here?

Comment: @KessVargavind Same here with XeTeX (with LuaTeX works fine). I'll have a look at it asap.

Comment: @KessVargavind If you need a quick fix, search for `\let\bbl@xenohyph\bbl@xenohyph@d` in `babel.sty` and replace it with `\global\let\bbl@xenohyph\bbl@xenohyph@d` (ie, add `\global` before `\let`).

Answer (score 2):

Javier Bezos solved your problem, but for a bit more of an explanation.

The `babel` package is great, but you just ran into one of its biggest problems.  You loaded

```
\usepackage[english,thai]{babel}
```

When you passed the `thai` option, `babel` loaded a file called `thai.ldf`.  It tries to load an 8-bit font and does not work with Unicode.  The dead giveaway is that you got an error message

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LTH/FreeSerif(0)/m/n' undefined using `LTH/norasi/m/n' instead [...]
```

LTH is an 8-bit Local THai encoding.  Any time XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX try to use an encoding other than TU, some package thinks it’s still in 8-bit world.

The example that worked did this instead:

```
\usepackage{babel}
\babelprovide[main, import]{thai}
```

This loads a definition of Thai that works in LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX.

So, use `\babelprovide` to load languages, then?  I thought so for a while.  Here’s the problem.  Javier Bezos, who maintains `babel`, tells me that’s wrong.  You’ll notice he fixed this with

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelprovide[import, main]{thai} % Remove main if the main language is english
```

As of 2020, you’re supposed to load some languages as package options to `babel`.  Others only work with `\babelprovide[import]`.

**Which way to load which language is not well-documented.**  I originally wrote, but deleted, a list of the clues you do get in the documentation about which to use, but the takeaway was: you need to figure it out by trial and error.

Comment: You've got a point. I'll try to clarify it either in the wiki or in the manual (or both).

Comment: And here is a preliminary draft: https://github.com/latex3/babel/wiki/Which-method-for-which-language . Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: @JavierBezos Looks like a big improvement. I have some recommendations on the font list, but I’m not sure where to leave them, and also, it’s bikeshedding.

Comment: You can contact me here: http://www.texnia.com/contact.html .

Comment: @JavierBezos Sent.

Answer (score 0):

The code below gets around the error and renders properly. Although the thread that Javier Bezos references provides clues as to what was wrong and could potentially go wrong, I still don't understand of all the things I've tried that seem to make sense in light of the information therein, only this solution works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\babelprovide[import, language=Default, main]{english}
\babelprovide[import, language=Default]{thai}
\babelfont{rm}{FreeSerif}

\begin{document}
Hello.

\begin{otherlanguage}{thai}
    สวัสดี
\end{otherlanguage}
\end{document}
```